# Flyout.showAt() ArgumentException based on Content

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to use a Flyout this way

```
 this.DefaultViewModel["SelectedVideo"] = vi;
 Flyout f = new Flyout();
 f.Content = this.videoFlyoutContent;
 f.ShowAt(videosGrid); // HERE I GET AN EXCEPTION
```

while I have the following XAML code

```
<Page.Resource>
    <!-- ................ -->
    <!-- ................ -->
    <x:Double x:Key="FlyoutWidth">500</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="FlyoutHeight">440</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="FlyoutTextWidth">400</x:Double>
    <ContentControl x:Name="videoFlyoutContent">
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedVideo}" Width="{StaticResource FlyoutWidth}" Height="{StaticResource FlyoutHeight}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail.hqDefault}" /> <!-- 480x360 -->
            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{Binding Title}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        Style="{StaticResource UNIListItemStyle_TitleTextBlock}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{StaticResource FlyoutTextWidth}"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource VideoElement_TextForeground}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now, the problem is that I get an ArgumentException in f.showAt();

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutBase.ShowAt(FrameworkElement placementTarget)
```

which is not raised if I remove the line

```
f.Content = this.videoFlyoutContent;
```

Comment: And the same happens if "videoFlyoutContent" is an empty grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved simply by using:

```
 <Page.Resources>
      <Flyout x:Name="myFlyout">
           <Grid>...</Grid>
      </Flyout>
  </Page.Resources>
```

and

```
  myFlyout.showAt(videosGrid);
```

but no idea of why it didn't work the other way.

Comment: Probably, it is because showAt() doesn't find the contentcontrol in the visual tree (it needs some "reference" in order to give the flyout a position in the screen). However, including the contentcontrol somewhere in the page content didn't seem to work.