# Problems with flyout over itemscontrol in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've got the following piece of XAML code:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding History}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Tapped="HistoryItemTapped">
                            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                <Flyout>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <ScrollViewer>
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneMidBrush}" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Expression}" />
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                        <ScrollViewer>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargePlusFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Result}" />
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Flyout>
                            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneMidBrush}" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Expression}" 
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargePlusFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Result}" 
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

There are two problems I can't solve:

1. The flyout is shown upon tapping on one of items:

   ```
   private void HistoryItemTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender).ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
   }
   ```

   However, no matter how I set up the flyout it always shows on the top of the screen, not over the tapped item. Why?
2. The flyout contains two TextBlocks on separate ScrollViewers. The text on one of them exceeds width of the flyout, bt the scrollviewer does not appear to be working (I cannot scroll horizontally the textblock). Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

So let's knock these out real quick. Your #1 would be expected result, it's just going off the default [FlyoutPlacementMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutplacementmode.aspx) enumeration wherein generally your flyout is just meant to appear over the top in one of 5 spots, Top, Bottom, Left, Right, or Full(Center)

How to fix it, ditch the flyout control and just animate your own panel to do the same thing on a tap event or whatever, not hard at all.

Your #2, if I remember right the default on `ScrollViewer`for something like the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is False by default. So just add HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" to it.

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Ok... so what is `FlyoutBase.ShowAt` supposed to do if flyout is always shown in the same place of the screen?

Comment: Ah yea sorry, could see how that could get misinterpreted, not of the screen, you've just got it setup wrong, check like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606049/flyout-showat-argumentexception-based-on-content)

Comment: Could you please guide me how to fix the code to display the flyout over a single item, not on the top of the screen?

Comment: Nah actually I owe you an apology man, I didn't see the windows-phone tag on your thing until just now. In which case you are restricted and would just need to make your own quick effect to simulate the same behavior which isn't hard either, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx) for a full write up on it, the phones a little different. Friday distractions :/